# Flask API running locally w/ docker-compose, but not responding (windows)

Tags: mysql, windows, docker, flask, docker-compose

I have a dev environment dockerized with a flask API, mysql, and redis.

When I run "docker-compose up", I get the following at the end of a long log output in the docker terminal

> Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

But the API is not loading in my web browser, and it's not responding to requests from Postman ("could not get a reponse" when I send any HTTP request to the URL).

Why does docker say the server is up and running, but it's not actually responding to anything?

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  api:
    build: .
    environment:
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 'true'
      MYSQL_HOSTNAME: mysql
      REDIS_URL: redis
    links:
      - mysql
      - redis
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
      redis:
        condition: service_started
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
  mysql:
    build: ./mysql
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/mysql
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "********", "-u", "******", "********", "ping"]
      interval: 2s
      timeout: 1s
      retries: 120
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
  redis:
    image: "redis:3.0-alpine"
    command: redis-server
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/redis/data
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
```

Here is the docker file:

```
FROM python:2.7
LABEL maintainer="Kento Noguchi"

ENV FLASK_ENV="dev"
ENV MYSQL_USER="root"
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD="password"
ENV SECRET_KEY="the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

# Place app in container..
COPY . /opt/www
WORKDIR /opt/www

# Install dependencies..
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN chmod +x ./load_db.sh

EXPOSE 5000
CMD sh ./load_db.sh && python server.py runserver --threaded -p 5000
```

And here is the output after I run "docker-compose up":

```
$ docker-compose up
Creating network "edinlabsapi_default" with the default driver
Creating edinlabsapi_redis_1
Creating edinlabsapi_mysql_1
Creating edinlabsapi_api_1
Attaching to edinlabsapi_redis_1, edinlabsapi_mysql_1, edinlabsapi_api_1
redis_1  | 1:C 10 Oct 02:11:43.157 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
mysql_1  | Initializing database
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:43.299048Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:43.440515Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:43.473964Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:43.529689Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 5c4fec40-ad60-11e7-9b35-0242ac120003.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:43.531612Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:43.531963Z 1 [Warning] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:43.927042Z 1 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:43.927126Z 1 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:43.927151Z 1 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:43.927239Z 1 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:43.927277Z 1 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1  | Database initialized
mysql_1  | Initializing certificates
mysql_1  | Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
mysql_1  | ..................................................................................+++
mysql_1  | .....................................................................................................................+++
mysql_1  | unable to write 'random state'
mysql_1  | writing new private key to 'ca-key.pem'
mysql_1  | -----
mysql_1  | Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
mysql_1  | ..........................................+++
mysql_1  | ...............+++
mysql_1  | unable to write 'random state'
mysql_1  | writing new private key to 'server-key.pem'
mysql_1  | -----
mysql_1  | Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
mysql_1  | .......................................................................+++
mysql_1  | ...........................................+++
mysql_1  | unable to write 'random state'
mysql_1  | writing new private key to 'client-key.pem'
mysql_1  | -----
mysql_1  | Certificates initialized
mysql_1  | MySQL init process in progress...
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.446286Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.447202Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.17) starting as process 91 ...
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.449818Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.449870Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.449884Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.450000Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.450013Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.450036Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.450206Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.450282Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.451269Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.457881Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.460140Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.471894Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.484684Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.484796Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.505413Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.507223Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.507301Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.507899Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.558783Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.17 started; log sequence number 2534561
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.560273Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.567602Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.567818Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.570849Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 171010  2:11:46
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.572069Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.580538Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.580706Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.580774Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.580814Z 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.584210Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.595396Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.595634Z 0 [Note] Executing 'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;' to get a list of tables using the deprecated partition engine. You may use the startup option '--disable-partition-engine-check' to skip this check.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.595676Z 0 [Note] Beginning of list of non-natively partitioned tables
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.613650Z 0 [Note] End of list of non-natively partitioned tables
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:46.613941Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
mysql_1  | Version: '5.7.17'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:47.450123Z 5 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
mysql_1  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
mysql_1  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
mysql_1  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.396509Z 6 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.396718Z 6 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.396794Z 6 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.396820Z 6 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.396902Z 6 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1  | mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysql_1  | mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.409488Z 8 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.409544Z 8 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.409576Z 8 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.409592Z 8 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.409716Z 8 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1  | mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysql_1  |
mysql_1  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/00_init_db.sql
mysql_1  |
mysql_1  |
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414120Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414151Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414164Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414175Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414207Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414706Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414722Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414733Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414742Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414750Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414761Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414770Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414779Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414797Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414805Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414813Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414820Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414828Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414835Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414896Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414906Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414914Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414921Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414929Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414936Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414944Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414962Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414970Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414978Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414986Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.414993Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.415001Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.415008Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.415016Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.415023Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.415031Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.415038Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.415046Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.415053Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.415061Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.415113Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.415278Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.519219Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:49.531444Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 171010  2:11:49
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.545809Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 12131606
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.551245Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.551455Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.551499Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.551552Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.551585Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.551614Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.551678Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.551712Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.552059Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.553201Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
mysql_1  |
mysql_1  |
mysql_1  | MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.
mysql_1  |
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.793971Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.795221Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.17) starting as process 1 ...
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.798668Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.798749Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.798763Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.798774Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.798782Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.798803Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.798966Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.799037Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.800458Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.805895Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.808466Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.821074Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.846882Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.847575Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.900217Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.901397Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.901446Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.901811Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.952504Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.17 started; log sequence number 12131606
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.952998Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.960585Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.961830Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.965617Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.970795Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.976413Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.976819Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.976901Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.976300Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 171010  2:11:50
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.985951Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.986136Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.987187Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.987274Z 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:50.995476Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:51.012317Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:51.012767Z 0 [Note] Executing 'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;' to get a list of tables using the deprecated partition engine. You may use the startup option '--disable-partition-engine-check' to skip this check.
mysql_1  | 2017-10-10T02:11:51.012849Z 0 [Note] Beginning of list of non-natively partitioned tables
api_1    | /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_cache/jinja2ext.py:33: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.cache is deprecated, use flask_cache instead.
api_1    |   from flask.ext.cache import make_template_fragment_key
api_1    | Creating directory /opt/www/migrations ... done
api_1    | Creating directory /opt/www/migrations/versions ... done
api_1    | Generating /opt/www/migrations/alembic.ini ... done
api_1    | Generating /opt/www/migrations/env.py ... done
api_1    | Generating /opt/www/migrations/script.py.mako ... done
api_1    | Generating /opt/www/migrations/README ... done
api_1    | Generating /opt/www/migrations/env.pyc ... done
api_1    | Please edit configuration/connection/logging settings in '/opt/www/migrations/alembic.ini' before proceeding.
api_1    | /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_cache/jinja2ext.py:33: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.cache is deprecated, use flask_cache instead.
api_1    |   from flask.ext.cache import make_template_fragment_key
api_1    | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl MySQLImpl.
api_1    | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
api_1    | INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'category'
api_1    | INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'device'
api_1    | INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'price'
api_1    | INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'skill'
api_1    | INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'users'
api_1    | INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'addresses'
api_1    | INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'products'
api_1    | INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'subcategory'
api_1    | INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'subskill'
api_1    | INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'pilots'
api_1    | INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'product_categories'
api_1    | INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'product_devices'
api_1    | INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'product_prices'
api_1    | INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'product_skills'
api_1    | INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'product_subcategories'
api_1    | INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'product_subskills'
api_1    | INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'surveys'
api_1    | INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'questions'
api_1    | INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'questions_checkbox'
api_1    | INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'questions_likert'
api_1    | INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'questions_long_input'
api_1    | INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'questions_range'
api_1    | INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'questions_short_input'
api_1    | INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'choices'
api_1    | Generating /opt/www/migrations/versions/4a7091cfe023_.py ... done
api_1    | /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_cache/jinja2ext.py:33: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.cache is deprecated, use flask_cache instead.
api_1    |   from flask.ext.cache import make_template_fragment_key
api_1    | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl MySQLImpl.
api_1    | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
api_1    | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade  -> 4a7091cfe023, empty message
api_1    | /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_cache/jinja2ext.py:33: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.cache is deprecated, use flask_cache instead.
api_1    |   from flask.ext.cache import make_template_fragment_key
api_1    |  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
api_1    |  * Restarting with stat
api_1    | /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_cache/jinja2ext.py:33: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.cache is deprecated, use flask_cache instead.
api_1    |   from flask.ext.cache import make_template_fragment_key
api_1    |  * Debugger is active!
```

Comment: Did you try using the ip of the docker machine instead of 0.0.0.0?

Comment: How are you testing it? Are you using Docker for windows or docker toolbox?

Comment: @MaartenBicknese how do I find the IP of the docker machine?

Comment: @TarunLalwani My front end (react) is getting errors, unable to make HTTP requests to it. Postman fails when trying to make HTTP requests. Also can not be accessed via web browser. 
I have docker installed (made sure it was latest version) via pip. I am running the command via Docker Quickstart Terminal

Comment: @MansoorSiddiqui, please check the answer

Comment: hey  did you get find the ans for this, I am having same issue with my flask API and mongoDB

Answer (score 0):

Using Docker quickstart Terminal means you are using docker toolbox and not Docker for windows.

You need to use the IP of your Docker VM to access the app in this.

Use `docker-machine ip` to get the IP and then browser `<ip>:5000` in the browser

Answer (score 0):

The IP address `0.0.0.0` is a full wildcard address. It matches every possible IP. This is useful when you want to bind a service to your server but don't know the address, or you don't want to bind your service to a single interface.

[Wikipedia page on 0.0.0.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0)

Yet the other way around, one cannot find servers by the wildcard IP. You'll need to actual reachable IP address to tell your browser or software to connect.

In this case it can be found by running:

```
docker-machine ip <machine>
```

or if you're using the default docker machine just simply:

```
docker-machine ip
```

[Official documentation on `docker-machine ip`](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/ip/)

Answer (score 0):

I know what is happening here, I had exact the same problem with a MongoDB and Flask-Nginx instance and is related to Windows and the way that the network works.(inside windows). Now I'm using hyper v with a ubuntu /Linux instance to run all my containers because Docker in windows was giving me headaches. Maybe this is not a solution, but I solved all my problems moving to hyper v w linux.